# how to show /hide div on mouseover when div set to display none, in gridview item template

Tags: jquery, asp.net, onmouseover

box div will be hidden during pageload, when we hover on it it should display, onmouseover it should display, and onmouseout it should be hidden. can any body suggest me how to do in jquery, i am beginner in Jquery :)

Update this Div is placed in ItemTemplate of gridview. will it be worked ? with answeered which you people provide ?

```
<div id="box" style="display: none">
   <a href="#" class="bt btleft">Highlight it</a>
   <a href="#" class="bt btright">Reset</a>
</div>
```

Comment: how would you define it being "over" it if its hidden, hidden elements have no visible area to be over.

Comment: Can't hover on what's not there. You need another trigger if the div is hidden.

Comment: well you can if you are using visibility property of CSS rather than display:none. visibility holds on to the space. Check my jsfiddle from my answer. Cheers!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you are better off using visible property in CSS rather than display:none to start with because display:none will sort of remove the space of the container itself.

try this out

http://jsfiddle.net/sfUHn/7/

Your HTML should look like this

```
<div id='container'>
 <div id="box" style="visibility: hidden">
 <a href="#" class="bt btleft">Highlight it</a>
 <a href="#" class="bt btright">Reset</a>
 </div>
</div>​
```

You jquery will look like this

```
 $("#container").hover(function () {
$("#container div").css("visibility","visible");
  },
  function () {
    $("#container div").css("visibility","hidden");
  });​
```

Hope this helps

Comment: can you check updated question, i have placed div in itemtemplate of gridview

Comment: 'itemTemplate of gridview' doesn't describe actual DOM nodes to people who don't use gridview. This technique will work fine as long as you substitute the container element for your actual container element.

Comment: @JaspreetChahal then whenever i hover it all div will be shown ? suppose 100 rows will be there, if i hover it on one row, will it show all row ?

Comment: @ravi does it answer your question? Cheers buddy!

Comment: This solution have issue with size of hidden block.

Answer (score 1):

modify the html a bit like

```
<div id="hover">hover</div>
<div id="box" style="display: none">
   <a href="#" class="bt btleft">Highlight it</a>
   <a href="#" class="bt btright">Reset</a>
</div>
```

jquery part

```
$("#hover").hover(function(){
  $("#box").slideDown();

},function(){
     $("#box").slideUp(); 
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/sfUHn/)

Comment: can you check the updated question, acutally i have placed div in itemtemplate of gridview

Comment: where ever it is placed you need to define the hover event handler that is visible like in my answer i have attached it to the visible div similarly you can attach the handler to some visible element of your grid

Answer (score 1):

wrap it in another div and bind a mouseover event on that div

```
<div id='parent-wrapper'>
  <div id="box" style="display: none">
     <a href="#" class="bt btleft">Highlight it</a>
     <a href="#" class="bt btright">Reset</a>
  </div>
</div>

$('#parent-wrapper')
 .mouseover( 
   function() {
    $('#box').show();
   } 
 );
```

Comment: check i updated question, i have placed it  in gridview itemptemplate column

Comment: if asp.net doesn't messes with js then it would work fine, i would recommend you to try it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, the simplest one..

```
$("#box").hover(function()
{
  $(this).show();
},
function()
{
  $(this).hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the `div` with another `div` and add the code to that wrapped `div`:

```
$('#wrapper').bind('mouseover hover', function(){

     $('#box').show();

});


$('#wrapper').mouseout(funcion(){

    $('#box').hide();

});
```

Comment: As per other answers, the div is hidden. Can't hover over it. Also, is "mouseover hover" a good way to bind? Why not just use the .hover() (which encapsulates mouseenter and mouseleave) or at least use parralel binding types.