# Smooth Show/hide div once hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, show-hide

I was working on my wordpress theme and i would like to implement the social button that hides and shows once mouse hover.

notice how [Mashable](http://mashable.com/) do it? any idea how to do it?

can you can help me by coding it in jsfiddle? thank you very much!

Comment: Asking for code is not what this site is for...? Better check some other sites for that.. OR check mashable's source..! If you're stuck somewhere with your code then post it...!

Comment: you can start looking at this post

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9372665/how-to-show-hide-div-on-mouseover-when-div-set-to-display-none-in-gridview-ite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can start looking at this post. The answer tackles your question.

[how to show /hide div on mouseover when div set to display none, in gridview item template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9372665/how-to-show-hide-div-on-mouseover-when-div-set-to-display-none-in-gridview-ite)

just try it out.